# I have 2d array, and i want to swap the value of the last index of each array

Tags: php, arrays

i want the last index value of each array **for example 8 and 10 will be swap**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}
```

so **the result** will be

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "5"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "6"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

if there are two value or more (even, not odd) will be swap its okay, as long as not all of the value will be swap. the *size of array will be dynamic*, thats just for example.

Comment: Can you add any code you have tried so far, we don't mind helping but some effort is appreciated.

Comment: What would the result be if there were 3 instead of two

Answer (score 0):

it swaps the last value:

```
$arr1 = array(1, 3, 5, 8);
$arr2 = array(1, 3, 6, 10);
$val1 = end($arr1);
$val2 = end($arr2);
array_pop($arr1);
array_pop($arr2);
array_push($arr1, $val2);
array_push($arr2, $val1);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```